# How to return a string with a Breadth First Order traversal of a binary search tree?

Tags: java, string

So I've figured out how to do a bread-first order for a binary search tree but I need to return a String with a breadth-first order traversal of the tree, how do I do that?

My Code:

```
 /**
 * Returns a breadth-first order String of tree elements.
 * 
 * @return a String with a breadth-first order traversal of the tree
 */
public String breadthFirstOrder() {

    Queue<Node<E>> queue = new LinkedList<Node<E>>();

     if (root == null)
         System.out.println("Empty tree");
     queue.clear();
     queue.add(root);
     while(!queue.isEmpty()){
         Node<E> node = queue.remove();
         System.out.print(node.data + " ");
         if(node.left != null) queue.add(node.left);
         if(node.right != null) queue.add(node.right);
        }

}
```

Comment: Pass a `StringBuilder` in as a parameter and append to it as you visit each node during the BFS.

Comment: what would it look like without a paremeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just define a String variable and add the `node.data`  to it while searching.

```
/**
 * Returns a breadth-first order String of tree elements.
 * 
 * @return a String with a breadth-first order traversal of the tree
 */
public String breadthFirstOrder() {

 Queue<Node<E>> queue = new LinkedList<Node<E>>();
 String traversal = "";
 if (root == null)
     System.out.println("Empty tree");
 queue.clear();
 queue.add(root);
 while(!queue.isEmpty()){
     Node<E> node = queue.remove();
     System.out.print(node.data + " ");
     traversal += node.data + " ";
     if(node.left != null) queue.add(node.left);
     if(node.right != null) queue.add(node.right);
    }
    return traversal;
}
```

Comment: I get an error on if(node.right != null) queue.add(node.rightjava and  Node<E> node = queue*remove();

Comment: whats node.rightjava and whats with the queue*remove()?

Comment: this time it should be ok.

Comment: Here's my test, is this what it's suppose to print out afterwards? multipleTree = new BinarySearchTree<Integer>();
  
  multipleTree.add(100);
  multipleTree.add(50);
  multipleTree.add(150);
  multipleTree.add(75);
  multipleTree.add(25);
  multipleTree.add(125);
  multipleTree.add(175); assertEquals("100 50 150 25 75 125 175" , multipleTree.breadthFirstOrder());

Comment: you can check your output info, it's the same as your `print` info, and I believe it's what you want.